# HTTPS AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, ssl, https, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to get my AWS Elastic Beanstalk environment to use HTTPS...however, when I open my site in a browser it is showing an insecure connection.

I'm not sure if this is an issue with my security groups or load balancer configuration...

[load balancer config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WUwgt.jpg)

[security group config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0lW1P.png)

Comment: "it is showing an insecure connection." can you please be more specific? Why does it say "insecure connection"? Does it say something like "hostname mismatch", etc?

Comment: @vcsjones It's just the general message that browsers show when your connection is not https. Essentially, it seems like the https is configured correctly but it's not reflected when I open my website

Comment: Is it because the certificate is self signed?

Comment: issued from aws

Comment: Just edited my answer with the solution in the bottom.

Comment: @AnthonyPecoraro Most browsers have an "advanced" or error code. For example, Chrome will say "NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID". Firefox, if you click advanced, will say "Error code: SSL_ERROR_BAD_CERT_DOMAIN" or something along those lines. It will be difficult to troubleshoot without an error code of some kind.

Comment: This one is on me. My browser was caching http. Setup Nginx server to force https and everything looks good now.

Answer (score 4):

You should assign a certificate to your environment's load balancer:

> 1. Open the Elastic Beanstalk console.
> 2. Navigate to the management page for your environment.
> 3. Choose Configuration.
> 4. On the Load balancer configuration card, choose Modify.
>
>    Note
>
>    If the Load balancer configuration card doesn't have a Modify button,
>      your environment doesn't have a load balancer.
> 5. On the Modify load balancer page, the procedure varies depending on
>      the type of load balancer associated with your environment.
>
>    Classic Load Balancer
>
>    - Choose Add listener.
>    - In the Classic Load Balancer listener dialog box, configure the
>        following settings:
>
>      - For Listener port, type the incoming traffic port, typically 443.
>      - For Listener protocol, choose HTTPS.
>      - For Instance port, type 80.
>      - For Instance protocol, choose HTTP.
>      - For SSL certificate, choose your certificate.
>    - Choose Add.
>
>    Application Load Balancer
>
>    - Choose Add listener.
>    - In the Application Load Balancer listener dialog box, configure the
>        following settings:
>
>      - For Port, type the incoming traffic port, typically 443.
>      - For Protocol, choose HTTPS.
>      - For SSL certificate, choose your certificate.
>    - Choose Add.
>
>      Note
>
>      If the drop-down menu doesn't show any certificates, you should create
>        or upload a certificate for your custom domain name in AWS Certificate
>        Manager (ACM) (preferred), or upload a certificate to IAM with the AWS
>        CLI.
> 6. Choose Apply.

Reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/configuring-https-elb.html

Edit: If you're issue is related to untrusted certificate, follow these steps: https://aws.amazon.com/pt/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/acm-certificate-error-https/

> If you imported a self-signed certificate using AWS Certificate Manager (ACM), the certificate might not be trusted by some browsers. To resolve this error, Request a Certificate using ACM or contact your CA.

Comment: These are the steps I followed. My load balancer has the certificate I believe

Comment: It seems that your browser isn't trusting the certificate. Check edit.